# Does it mean I can write my Selenium test cases in this many languages?

Tags: selenium

> Selenium can be coded in multiple languages:
> JAVA,C#,Python,Javascript, PHP, Ruby

Does it mean I can write my Selenium test cases in this many languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write your test cases in many languages. Yet, there is no much logic doing that. You either work with Visual Studio and `C#`, VS Code and `JavaScript` or simply IntelliJ and `Java`.

You can Not use a single IDE and write tests in all the languages you mentioned.